# AutoCompleteView load data from database

Tags: android, sqlite, autocompletetextview

In my android application I have a database of around 1000 rows of data in one table. I have an auto complete text view when user enters a key it hast to drop-down appropriate item from the db table how can I do this.

**database fetching code**

```
public Map<String, String> getSimilarStems(String stem) {
    Map<String, String> results = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT word, _id FROM words_en WHERE stems LIKE '%"+stem+" %' OR stems LIKE '"+stem+"' ORDER BY LENGTH(word) LIMIT 10", null);

    while(res.moveToNext()) {
        String id = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String word = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("word"));            
        results.put(id, word);          
    }
    return results;
}
```

please anyone help me to bind the data from the database with the AutoCompleteView

Answer (score 1):

> bind the data from the database with the AutoCompleteView

To bind data from database to `AutoCompleteView` you will need to use Adapter for passing all values from database.

You have two option for creating adapter

**1.** Use default ArrayAdapter :

```
 Map<String, String> allItems=getSimilarStems(<parms>);
// Create List from Map values
List<String> valueList=new ArrayList<String>(allItems.values());
// Create ArrayAdapter
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
   (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,valueList);
// Set Adapter for AutoCompleteTextView
   Autocompletetextview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2. Create custom adapter for showing auto complete text using Map. see following tutorial :

[AutocompleteTextView with Custom Adapter](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite.html)

Comment: will it take more time to fetch all the data from db ? sps if I have more than 1000 data.

Comment: @cybro: probably yes but you can use `AsyncTask`  for fetching data from db then show it in Autocompletetextview

Comment: @cybro: i'm not getting your question?

Comment: @cybro: if you think if you have  more then 1000 records then search will slow then try it using SimpleCursorAdapter [Android: Simpler AutoCompleteTextView with SimpleCursorAdapter](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/) to query database directly

Comment: I think the data will be around 20k, anyway I'll try